# How to align overflowing text horizontally?

Tags: html, css, alignment, overflow

I have some text that can overflow the parent container:

```css
body {
  margin: 200px;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Short Text
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    Very long text that should not wrap and be center aligned
  </div>
</div>
```

When text is short, it is center aligned, as expected.

However, when the text overflows the container, it's not center aligned anymore.

How could I align the text horizontally regardless of the length of the text?

Desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: By setting "header" position to "relative"? https://jsfiddle.net/b8c2w3rL/

Comment: Your hard-coded `right` value won't work if text changes.

Comment: Yeah, How about having linear-gradient as a "background" to the text. So, that we can position the grey background in the middle.  Like this https://jsfiddle.net/b8c2w3rL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
   <div>Short Text</div>
  </div>
 <div class="header">
  <div>Very long text that should not wrap and be center aligned</div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 200px;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

for demo here, https://jsfiddle.net/jinny/qs7wL4nv/33/

Comment: answer was as per your question before you edited, now it updated

Answer (score 0):

Use text-indent:

```css
body {
  margin: 200px;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-indent: -8em; 
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      Short Text
     </div>
     <div class="header">
      Very long text that should not wrap and be center aligned
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

flexbox can do this easily

```css
body {
  margin:0 200px;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
}

.header {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Short Text
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    Very long text that should not wrap and be center aligned
  </div>
</div>
```